# Is getting an echo'd username using Javascript with display none CSS bad for security?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a PHP page that can only be accessed by logged in users. Each page is unique to that particular user and is used for collection tracking.

Through PHP I have the `username` and `user id` echo'd and then wrapped in a `display:none` div.

I then have a couple of ajax calls that pass the `username` and `user id` when they do specific tasks (update collection, add to, delete, etc etc). This is passed to a PHP file which uses prepared statements.

I do this since I can't seem to find another way to grab the `username` and `user id` in Javascript.

Since each page is accessed only by that particular user, I'm thinking it's safe since you can't get access to another users username or ID. However I can't help but feel that this is extremely bad practice. I'm completely open to suggestions on this!

EDIT: I should also point out that I am using WordPress for authentication.

Comment: You should not need the username or id in JavaScript. Use sessions to identify the user, or take a look at [jwt tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think about is ensuring you sanitise the values when you read them. For example what would happen if someone manually set the username in that div to `DROP ALL TABLES;` - a sql injection attack. Also why not have it as a JS variable by echoing it in a script rather than a hidden div? Otherwise it seems fine, indeed most web applications serialise data into html template to be read by scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Wouldn't the fact that I am using prepared statements mitigate the sql injection?

Comment: I think this answer has the concept wrong and too many people jump the gun when it comes to security. Prepared statements will mitigate this, however, since you're using integers to verify access to information, this can easily be modified and sent to the server. You really need to look at using JWT as stated as part of the comment, giving everyone a unique session. This does not hide that same integer value, it only verifies that the JWT was established on that application thus stopping people using random integers. You can echo data into scripts, however, I'd suggest using an API instead.

Comment: for example, (JQuery example) `$.get('/api/user', function(data) {})` <-- this endpoint will then access the `$_SESSION` which contains the JWT, verifies that JWT is authorised and then returns json encoded data on the current user. Note this should not be made a public endpoint (CORS disabled). People also use these to verify that a request come from a verified domain. Just an extra point to note which you could deploy to your application.